# Autoscaling child scrollable div when parent's div resized

Tags: css, html

I have a nested scrollable `div`. I need to automatically change its height via **CSS**, when I change the height of the parent `div`. How to do it? I would be very grateful for the help.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#main_container').resizable({handles: 'n,e'});
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">

#main_container {  
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px; 
  height: 300px;
}

#sub_container {
  max-height:80%; 
  overflow:auto;
}

#scrollable_container {
  height:100000em; 
  width:50em;  
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="main_container">
   <div id="sub_container">
      <div id="scrollable_container">
         test_content<br/>
         test_content<br/>
         test_content<br/>
         test_content<br/>
         test_content<br/>
         test_content<br/>
         test_content<br/>
         test_content<br/>
      </div>                  
   </div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w9SdX/

Comment: If it solved should i post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Following external files for **jQuery resizable**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9SdX/)

```
#sub_container {
  max-height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('#main_container').resize(function() {
    var newHeight = $(this).innerHeight() * 0.8;
    $("#sub_container").css('height', newHeight + 'px');
});
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the resizing function you are using... What happens when you apply somehing like `height:80%` to #sub_container?